# можно ли сразу удалить все ссылки на объект в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть объект и переменная(например a), которая ссылается на него , ещё есть список , в котором тоже есть ссылка на этот объект.

```
del a
```

Ссылки a больше нет , а в массиве есть )
Можно сделать так , чтобы удалялись сразу все ссылки , а не приходилось бы искать их в списке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ответ нет

```
a = 1
b = a, 2
# если бы было можно удалить все ссылки, все равно невоможно удалить a из b, те из tuple
del a
```